# How to show soap request xml for a web service call?

Tags: asp.net, soap, service, request

I am using a web method of a company's web service.

This web method requires one parameter when calling it:

```
CompanyOpereations srv = new CompanyOperations();
srv.getCustomerInfo(input);
```

How can I see my soap request xml when calling this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want to see it? If it's inside the code; I don't know. (Un)Fortunately .NET does a pretty good job of hiding it for the developer.

However, if you just want to debug the calls and nothing else: try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/). It will show you the Request/Response (including headers and everything else) for the webservice calls. This is what we use for debugging webservices. But you can use it for everything that uses the HTTP protocol for communication.